# Getting irrationally bound open sets from the rational basis producing the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Self-studying Topology from Munkres, and in chapter 2, he mentions that the collection of open sets $$\mathcal{B} = \{\,(a,b) \mid a < b, a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \,\}$$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ which produces the usual topology. I get the intuition behind this (I think) but how would one produce open sets like $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ from the above basis? We need to be able to get as close to $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ as possible. Do we have to specify a sequence in the rationals to get this? Is there a "nicer" way of being able to produce such an (irrationally bound) open set?

Comment: $$
(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = \bigcup_{ \substack{q_1, q_2 \in (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) \cap \Bbb Q \\ q_1 < q_2} } (q_1, q_2)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a < b$ be two arbitrary real numbers. We claim that the following equality holds:
$$(a, b) = \bigcup_{q_{1}, q_{2} \in \mathbb{Q} \\a \leq q_{1} < q_{2} \leq b} (q_{1}, q_{2}).$$ For ease of notation, we will denote the union on the right hand side by $I_{a, b}$.

First, consider an arbitrary element $r$ of $(a, b)$. We must have $a < r < b,$ and since the rationals are dense in the reals, there exist $q_{1}, q_{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a < q_{1} < r,$ and $r < q_{2} < b$. It is clear that $r$ is contained in $(q_{1}, q_{2}),$ and that $(q_{1}, q_{2})$ is a subset of $I_{a, b}.$ So, $r$ is an element of $I_{a, b},$ showing the inclusion
$$(a, b) \subseteq I_{a, b}.$$

Now, consider an arbitrary element $t$ of $I_{a, b}$. It is clear from the definition of $I_{a, b}$ that there exist some $q_{1}, q_{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, with $a \leq q_{1} < q_{2} \leq b$, such that $t \in (q_{1}, q_{2}).$ Of course, this means that $q_{1} < t < q_{2},$ and since $a \leq q_{1} < q_{2} \leq b$, it follows that $a < t < b$ as well. From this, we conclude that $t \in (a, b)$, hence the inclusion
$$I_{a, b} \subseteq (a, b)$$ holds.

We have shown both inclusions, so we conclude that
$$(a, b) = I_{a, b}.$$ Setting $a = \sqrt{2}$, $b = \sqrt{3}$ gives you a way to write $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ as a union of sets from the given collection $\mathcal{B}$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ is indeed an open set in the topology from the rational interval bases we need to show that for each $x \in (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ we have a member of $\mathcal B$ inbetween $x$ and $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ and this is easy enough: if $\sqrt{2} < x$ we can find some rational $q_1$ such that $\sqrt{2}< q_1 < x$ because between any two real numbers always lies some rational number. Likewise we have $q_2 \in \Bbb Q$ so that $x < q_2 < \sqrt{3}$ and then $x \in (q_1, q_2) \subseteq (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, as required.

Yes you can also use a sequence of rationals $q_n$ converging to $\sqrt{2}$ from the right, and a sequence of rationals $r_n$ converging to $\sqrt{3}$ from the left and prove that $\bigcup_n (q_n, r_n) = (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ as well. Whatever you prefer.